# How to navigate and dispatch action together? Nuxt, Vuex

Tags: nuxt.js, vuex

I am using Nuxt dynamic routing to navigate to pages, all i wanted is to dispatch action and navigate all together on a click of a button.

```
                        <v-btn
                          rounded
                          depressed
                          dark
                          color="green"
                          @click="fetchSocietyData()"
                          :to="'societies/' + sname"
                          nuxt
                          >Show Details</v-btn
                        >

                        <v-btn
                          v-if="$auth.loggedIn"
                          rounded
                          depressed
                          dark
                          color="blue"
                          :to="'societies/_ed/' + sname"
                          nuxt
                          >Edit Details</v-btn
                        >
                      </v-flex>
..
.
.
.
.
.
      async fetchSocietyData() {
      await this.$store.dispatch("societystore/fetchSpecificSocietyDetails", {
        id: this.id,
      });
      // console.log(this.id);
    },
```

it navigates to the page without dispatching, and if i remove the route (:to) it dispatches successfully.
any help would be appreciated :) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `fetchSocietyData` method, you could have something like

```js
await this.$store.dispatch("societystore/fetchSpecificSocietyDetails", {
  id: this.id,
})
this.$router.push({ path: `societies/${this.sname}` })
```

This way, you're making your action, waiting for it to finish, then programmaticaly navigating.
More info here: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#router-push-location-oncomplete-onabort

Of course, being sure that the action is successful before navigating could be a good thing.

Btw, the listener should be `@click="fetchSocietyData"`, no need of parentheses, otherwise you could have some unexpected behavior.